# Advantages of using package "nowidow" over \clubpenalty or \widowpenalty

Tags: widows-orphans

Consider the following **Minimum Working Example (MWE)**:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext

    This is a sample text to visualize the behavior of useful package nowidow. It clearly shows that only one line visible on the previous page is prevented (what is called the effect of Hurenkind). If there is only one line on the next page, this effect is called Schusterjunge. I hope one can understand the undesired behavior of both typesetting effects. Blabla blub test bla blub bla bla bla and some more blabla to cause LaTeX to produce some Hurenkind.

    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

As you can see, the package `nowidow` prevents the appearance of an ugly single line on the second page. Also it does prevent appearance of one single line on the first page before pagebreak.

---

**The question:**

Some similar protective behavior could be caused by setting

```
\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000
\displaywidowpenalty = 10000
```

in the preamble. What are the advantages of using package `nowidow` over using these single commands (or vice versa)?

Comment: possibly better than either: https://ctan.org/pkg/widows-and-orphans

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: May you want to post this as an answer or additional idea? Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: It seems more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference.

With the package option `defaultlines=<number>`, you can set the number of lines that should be kept together; so, with

```
\usepackage[defaultlines=3,all]{nowidow}
```

at least *three* lines will be moved to the next page.

You can get the same effect by loading the package without options and issuing

```
\setnowidow[3]
```

By default the package doesn't act on club lines. You can use

```
\setnoclub[3]
```

if you prefer to keep at least three lines before a page break.

The package also provides for `\nowidow[<number>]` to be used at the end of a paragraph in order to locally force `<number>` lines after the page break. Similarly for `\noclub`.